# jquery-datatables-rails not showing up after a link_to but does other times

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I am trying to get Jquery-data-table in rails 4.0 (ruby 2.2) to work.  In a strange way it does.  If I goto the Index view in my Groups controller (snippet):

```
<%- model_class = Group -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize.titleize %></h1>
</div>

<!-- table class="table table-striped"  id="groups" -->
<table class="display"  id="groups">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:id) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:name) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:address) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:city) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:phone) %></th>
      etc..
```

I have the required javascript for the jquery data tables in the groups.js file

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#groups").DataTable({paging:true, 
                            pagingType: 'full_numbers'
    });
});
```

And this works, if I goto the url:
`localhost:3000/groups'

it works, I see the data table, empty, or with data whichever the database state is it works and with searching.  The problem is if I goto and create a new group... and save it, it goes to the show, and the I click back to goto the index, then it shows the table as if no jquery-data-tables was there.  The headings look different, no pagination, no search, nothing.  If I click the above url and press enter it loads fine again.

Same thing if I go from my home page to the groups controller without typing it into the url box but by using a link_to with a bootstrap3 button like here:(from homepage index html)

```
<%= link_to groups_path do %>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Group
                </button>
            <% end %>
```

Then this works, it takes you to the groups and shows all the data in a table but it is not a jquery datatable.  This is making me go bonkers no idea why typing it in the URL bar and going there works when a link_to or a 'back' on a show form (groups_path) isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same issue as you, and solved it by the following step.

change the 1st line in "groups.js" file to

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
```

The information is from:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events

Answer (score -1):

You are using rails 4, The problem with turbolink add data-turbolinks false with your link to as:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', index_path, "data-turbolinks" => "false" %>
```